# Complile and use a realtime kernel on CentOS 7

Tags: linux-kernel, real-time, centos7, patch

I would like to compile and use a realtime kernel on CentOS 7. I found a guid on the web:
http://jensd.be/589/linux/complile-and-use-a-realtime-kernel-on-centos-7-or-rhel-7

When I try to useit I can see the new kernel is created, but when I try to use it I get error on boot:

"failed to mount /sysroot"

If someone has any idea how to fix it or have used real time kernel on centos 7 I will be glad for help.
Thanks

Comment: This is not a programming question. It probably should go on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: posted it there also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/491884/compile-and-use-a-realtime-kernel-on-centos-7